# How to use Perl Digest::xxHash to calculate hash of a file

Tags: perl, hash

https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::xxHash shows how to calculate the hash of a string.

```
my $hex_64  = xxhash64_hex( $data, $seed );
```

How can the hash of a large file be calculated quickly using this module?

Comment: Read the entire file into a string (Using `File::Slurper`, `Path::Tiny`, etc.). Hash that.

Comment: Those bindings are not complete. They do not provide bindings for incremental updates to data. The underlying `xxhash` library  itself supports it. You might need to write your own bindings or find another library that may provide it.

Comment: File::Map may help. You don't need to read in the data at all because it stays on disk.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to brian d foy for this solution:

```
use Digest::xxHash;
use File::Map 'map_file';
map_file my $data, $file, '+<';
my $seed;
my $hex_64 = xxhash64_hex( $data, $seed );
```

The large file may be GB in size, so I didn't want to try to slurp it into memory like this:

```
use Digest::xxHash;
sysopen my $fh, $file, 0 or die;
my $data = do { local $/; <$fh> };
my $seed;
my $hex_64 = xxhash64_hex( $data, $seed );
```